# Derived functors of Lower shriek in etale cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, derived-functors, etale-cohomology

Suppose $f:X \longrightarrow Y$ is a morphism (quasi-finite or compactifiable), $\mathcal{F} \in X_{et}$. What do the stalks of $R^{1}f_{!}\mathcal{F}$ look like?

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Does something like $(R^i f_!\mathcal{F})_\overline{y}=H^i_c(X_{(\overline{y})},\mathcal{F}_{\overline{y}})$ appeal to you? Here $X_{(\overline{y})}=X\times_Y\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{Y,(\overline{y})})$ where $\mathcal{O}_{Y,(\overline{y})}$ is the etale local ring of $Y$ at $\overline{y}$ (i.e. $\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}^\text{sh})$. Perhaps @Roland might have something more to say.

Comment: ah, sorry. I realised that I was mixing up two different notions of lower shriek.